# Size a UIToolbar to fit its items?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitoolbar

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to make a `UIToolbar` only as wide as it needs to be to fit the items that it contains. Is there a way to either:

- Configure the `UIToolbar` to adjust its width automatically as its items are changed?
- Programatically determine the minimum width required by the items, which can then be used to set the `UIToolbar`'s frame?

I haven't been able to figure this out due to the spacing between the items and the fact that `UIBarButtonItem`s are not `UIView` subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

After trying some suggestions from other answers that did not work unless I used custom views, or unless everything was loaded, I finally arrived at a way to set the toolbar width based on its items:

```
//Add bar items to toolbar first.

UIView* v = toolbar.subviews.lastObject;
float newWidth = v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.width;

//Set toolbar width
```

You'll need to override `UIToolbar -setItems:` or otherwise detect changed buttons to autoresize.

I have included this feature in my refactoring library, [es_ios_utils](https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils/blob/master/es_ios_utils/ESUICategories.m), to set a navigation item's right item with multiple buttons.  In the preceding link, see `UIToolbar +toolbarWithItems:` and `UINavigationItem -setRightBarButtonItems`.

Comment: There is no subviews on the `UIToolbar`.

Comment: @Dmitry, `UIToolbar` inherits from `UIView`, which indeed has `subviews`.

Comment: Thank you for the clairification. I haven't tested it in 11, but when do you set a breakpoint? If you break after the view is fully usable, is this still true?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the documentation and seems like UIBarButtonItems, even though they are not UIView subclasses, they have an attribute [width](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarButtonItem). I didn't try it myself, but I think you could sum each item's width, including the flexible item, and get the width for your toolbar.
Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure that the width is 0 unless explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3, 4 update

I have a toolbar with barButtonItem initiated with image. All I need to do is to calculate the total width of the images plus the intervals (margin.)

Margin is by default 11 in width. The code will be:

```
let width: CGFloat = YourBarButtonItemList.reduce(0) {sofar, new in
    if let image = new.image {
        return sofar + image.size.width + 11
    } else {
        return sofar + ADefaultValueIfThisDoesntWork + 11
    }
}
```